# Query if my workspace has the latest files using the TFS Api

Tags: c#, .net, tfs-sdk

I want to programmatically find out if a workspace has the latest files. I don't want to do a `Workspace.Get()`, because that performs the equivalent of "Get Latest". I just want to know if my workspace needs a "Get Latest" or not.

I'm doing this check during a Build.I plan on having a method like so:

```
public static bool HasLatestFiles(Workspace ws)
{
    bool hasChanges = false;

    /* need correct code to query if ws has latest files */

    return hasChanges;
}
```

What is the correct code to use?

Comment: PS: I found the `hasChanges=false` very confusing. Since you'd need to return the inverse to tell if the user has the latest files.

Comment: PS: If you plan to do a get-latest anyway if the workspace is 'stale', then you might as well just call Get-Latest. That's faster.

Comment: Sorry about the "hasChanges=false", that was leftover from several different things I tried.  I do not plan to do a get-latest, but I want to inform the builder that he doesn't have the latest files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Workspace.Get(LatestVersionSpec.Instance, GetOptions.Preview)` then check the `GetStatus.NoActionNeeded` that is yielded by the `Get` operation.

So:

```
public static bool HasLatestFiles(Workspace ws)
{
    GetStatus result = ws.Get(LatestVersionSpec.Instance, GetOptions.Preview);

    bool hasLatestFiles = result.NoActionNeeded;

    return hasLatestFiles;
}
```

Comment: How do you get the latest version? I noticed that using the command in Source Control in VS.NET is significantly faster than calling the API `workspace.Get(new GetRequest(targetBranch, RecursionType.Full, VersionSpec.Latest), GetOptions.GetAll);`

Comment: I think you don't want getall, that forces all files to ge overwritten, not just changed files.